# jQuery, toggle button to display plus or minus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How do I toggle toggle the button to display plus or minus?** 
The button enlarges and reduces the text. If text is large...button is
 minus, if text is small...button is plus etc.

I had some help on this yesterday, I'm still trying to learn jQuery and kind-of-stuck.
Thanks for your help,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var fontSizes = [14, 16]

$(function(){
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('p').css('font-size', fontSizes[0] + 'pt');
    fontSizes.reverse();
var currFontSize = ourText.css('fontSize');
var finalNum = parseFloat(currFontSize, 10);
var stringEnding = currFontSize.slice(-2);
if(this.id == 'large') {
finalNum *= 1.2;
}
else if (this.id == 'small'){
finalNum /=1.2;
}
ourText.css('fontSize', finalNum + stringEnding);
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Toggle Size? </h2>

<!--TOGGLE BUTTON NEEDS TO CHANGE FROM PLUS TO MINUS-->
<input type='button' value='+' id='small' />


<p>My Text!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/TebyM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you keep your function small? Like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var fontSizes = [14, 16]

$(function(){
  $('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "+") {
 $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'pt');
  $(this).val("-");
  }
  else {
   $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'pt');
  $(this).val("+");
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Toggle Size? </h2>

<!--TOGGLE BUTTON NEEDS TO CHANGE FROM PLUS TO MINUS-->
<input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus' />
<p id="OurText">My Text!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eric's answer is again cleaner. toggle is a built in function in jquery.  $().toggle(function, function);

Answer (score 3):

Going one stage further from [mahesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196745/jquery-toggle-button-to-display-plus-or-minus/5196958#5196958), use `$().toggle(function, function)`:

```
var fontSizes = [14, 16];

$(function(){
    $('#PlusMinus').toggle(function() {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'pt');
        $(this).val("-");
    }, function() {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0] + 'pt');
        $(this).val("+");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't konw if you need the font size in the js for some reason,
but this would be my take on it:

css:

```
p.large{
    font-size:1.2em;   
}

input{
    padding:0 5px;   
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {

    $('input').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).val('-');
        $('p').addClass('large');
    }, function() {
        $(this).val('+');
        $('p').removeClass('large');
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4xyF/